# updating / maintaining bootstrap web design with LESS mixins

Tags: less, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is it possible to maintain/update bootstrap with LESS like so:

Imagine earlier version, for this example 2.3.2, it includes classes like span4, span12, etc. I would have custom-bootstrap.less like so:

```
.myown4columnclass {
    .span4;
}
```

Then, the new version comes along, 3.0.0 I'd like to change custom-bootstrap.less to:

```
.myown4columnclass {
    .col-md-4;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure! As long as you make a habit of using your own custom class wrapper. If .col-md-4 differs heavily from .span4 you could also make tweaks in your class "wrapper" like

```
.myown4columnclass {
    .col-md-4; (might have a margin you don't like)
    margin: 10px; (fixes it)
}
```